# Error: A non-null value must be returned since the return type 'Never' doesn't allow null. Never convertPlatformException(Object exception, StackTrace

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, crashlytics

I am trying to integrate Firebase Crashlytics into a Flutter app(counter example code). I am getting the above error even after upgrading to Flutter 3.0.0 from Flutter 2.2.1.

Debug Console Output:

```
/C:/src/fl/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_crashlytics_platform_interface-3.2.0/lib/src/method_channel/utils/exception.dart:13:11: Error: Method not found: 'Error.throwWithStackTrace'.
    Error.throwWithStackTrace(exception, stackTrace);
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

/C:/src/fl/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_crashlytics_platform_interface-3.2.0/lib/src/method_channel/utils/exception.dart:16:9: Error: Method not found: 'Error.throwWithStackTrace'.
  Error.throwWithStackTrace(
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/fl/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_crashlytics_platform_interface-3.2.0/lib/src/method_channel/utils/exception.dart:11:7: Error: A non-null value must be returned since the return type 'Never' doesn't allow null.
Never convertPlatformException(Object exception, StackTrace stackTrace) {
      ^
3

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\src\fl\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1005

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\src\fl\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 16s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

Flutter doctor:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.675], locale en-IN)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[X] Visual Studio - develop for Windows
    X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary for Windows development.
      Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
      Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components
[√] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
[√] VS Code (version 1.67.2)
[√] Connected device (4 available)
[√] HTTP Host Availability

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Please suggest how to solve this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try update your version lib to `firebase_crashlytics: ^2.8.0`

Check and update your sdk to use `sdk: ">=2.17.1 <3.0.0"` in `pubspec.yaml`

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.17.1 <3.0.0"
```

Then `flutter pub upgrade` > `flutter clean` > `flutter pub get`

Comment: Thanks for answering, I go the following error after doing what you suggested:   The current Dart SDK version is 2.14.2.
Because flutter_example_1 requires SDK version >=2.17.0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; Because flutter_example_1 requires SDK version >=2.17.0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.)

Comment: update your Dart SDK to 2.17.1 @YashwanthRavula

Comment: I am using flutter 3.0.0, the corresponding dart version for it is dart 2.17.0.      flutter --version
Flutter 3.0.0 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision ee4e09cce0 (13 days ago) • 2022-05-09 16:45:18 -0700
Engine • revision d1b9a6938a
Tools • Dart 2.17.0 • DevTools 2.12.2

Comment: When I run 'flutter --version' it is showing dart 2.17.0. But when I run the app, the debug console output is showing  dart version as 2.14.2

Comment: Try in android studio , File > Invalidate Caches > Invalidate and Restart